# Xcode 6 custom launch screen

Tags: xcode6, launch, size-classes

I am trying to make a custom launch screen based Xcode 6 new feature following the content given [here](http://oleb.net/blog/2014/08/replacing-launch-images-with-storyboards/). I don't understand how can I manage orientation of launch screen on iPad. My launch screen contains a horizontal rectangular image in the centre. Using size classes I can set different constraints and views for iPhone in landscape or portrait mode. But unable to do the same for iPad. Also how can I lock the orientation of Launch screen when creating a launch screen using the above method ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can not do this for the iPad because both orientations fall under the regular width and regular height size class.